# Как создать уникальный ключ Hibernate, если в исходной таблице нет уникального поля ID?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

У меня есть таблица, в которой нет уникального поля, но для хибернейта нужно поле id. Я создавал поле ID, но получал ошибку, что такого поля нет в самой таблице. Насколько я понимаю, от меня требуется создать суррогатный ключ, подскажите, как это сделать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону композитных ключей. Вот хорошее объяснение https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys